# Angular - Set form value from inside a clickListener of OpenLayers

Tags: angular, openlayers-3

I'm trying to set a simple form text field containing the longitute and latitute from inside of a clicklistener of OpenlLayers. As a result I get

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined

Why is this.lat and this.long producing an undefined? I guess because I'm inside of this listener, because when I set a value in that ngOnInit method it works. How can I set the value from inside of the clickListener? What am I missing?

```
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

declare var ol: any;

@Component({
  selector: "app-spotcreation",
  templateUrl: "./spotcreation.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./spotcreation.component.css"]
})
export class SpotcreationComponent implements OnInit {
  source = new ol.source.OSM();

  map: any;

  lon = new FormControl();
  lat = new FormControl();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.map = new ol.Map({
      target: "map",
      controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: {
      collapsible: false
    }
      }),
      layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: this.source
    })
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([18.405, 45.095]),
    zoom: 8
      })
    });

    this.map.on("click", this.clickListener);
  }

  clickListener = function(args) {
    var lonlat = ol.proj.transform(args.coordinate, "EPSG:3857", "EPSG:4326");

    var latitude = lonlat[0];
    var longitude = lonlat[1];

    this.lat.setValue(latitude);
    this.lon.setValue(longitude);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the context which is changed. That is why `lat` and `lon` is not accessible. You can modify your as below to ensure you are not loosing the current class context.

```
    this.map.on("click", args=>{
       var lonlat = ol.proj.transform(args.coordinate, "EPSG:3857", "EPSG:4326");
       var latitude = lonlat[0];
       var longitude = lonlat[1];
       this.lat.setValue(latitude);
       this.lon.setValue(longitude);
    })
```

Do not forget to remove function `clickListener` since the code has been moved inside the `map.on` function.

Comment: That works! Perfect thank you. I'll mark it as the correct answer in 4 minutes :)